# Return value from MarketplaceReviewTask

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to integrate rate my app into my app, i can get it functioning fine with:

```
MarketplaceReviewTask marketplaceReviewTask = new MarketplaceReviewTask();

marketplaceReviewTask.Show();
```

but i can't get a return value to show whether the user actually rated or pressed cancel, as I'm wanting to offer a freebie for rating the app.

thanks.

Comment: if have seen a similar question, on here saying it can't be done but i have played games where it hasnt given me the reward until i do actually review the game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, MarketplaceReviewTask does not have any events which return a value whether user rated your app or not. A case with most of the Launcher tasks. Chooser tasks have events to collect the information.

But, here is a [Link](http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/detect-whether-user-has-reviewed-your-app-or-not-wpdev/) that tries to get back the user rating information using an API, see if this helps.